# What should I look for in an object when securing a laptop with a Kensington lock?

Tags: laptop, physical-security, kensington-lock

When I secure my laptop to an object using a Kensington lock, what features should I be looking for in that object to help ensure that my laptop is as safe as possible?

A table doesn't work, since as one person says, "A table is topologically equivalent to a sphere". And that makes sense - since someone could pull the table up.

He suggested a chair with a closed loop (more topologically equivalent to a donut), but someone could bring the chair to the bathroom and cut the lock.

The 3rd suggestion was a door handle on a counter. Which is what I ultimately used. But there is one issue with that: it's next to the sink, and so it increases the chances that someone might accidentally spill something on it (or accidentally step on it).

Comment: also what happens when the door opens / closes ?!

Answer (score 4):

Basically if you leave your device on area where no one controls the physical actions taken, the Kensington lock is not going to prevent your equipment from being stolen. So choosing an item that's hard to move without drawing much attention works as well.

One good item are bar chairs or table with similar structure: both ends widening considerably and middle part being relatively thin. Both of these are also usually heavy enough to make it very hard to move them without drawing lots of attention.